# JavaScript: Get ID from currently dragged CLASS item

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, nodes

My application has multiple stones:
-> "let dragStone"
and one container where one of these stones can be placed:
-> "let putCircleNextStoneField"

I want to append the container (parent node) with the stone that is dragged onto it (child node).
The Error code is: "Parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'".

I know that the parameter isn't working beacause the dragStone variable isn't just a reference to the ID but an array-like object of all child elements which have the CLASS name: ".stone".

How do I get the reference to the id of the stone that is currently dragged?

```
function dragFromStoneFieldToNextStoneField() {
    let dragStone = document.querySelector("#stoneField").querySelectorAll(".stone");
    let putCircleNextStoneField = document.querySelector("#nextStoneField");

    dragStone.forEach(stone => {
        stone.classList.add("cursorPointer");
    });

    dragStone.forEach(stone => {
        stone.addEventListener("dragstart", () => {

        });
    });

    putCircleNextStoneField.addEventListener("dragover", e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        putCircleNextStoneField.classList.add("draggedOver");

        putCircleNextStoneField.appendChild(dragStone); //ERROR IN THIS LINE

    });

    putCircleNextStoneField.addEventListener("dragleave", e => {
        putCircleNextStoneField.classList.remove("draggedOver");
    });

    putCircleNextStoneField.addEventListener("drop", e => {
        putCircleNextStoneField.classList.remove("draggedOver");
    });
}

dragFromStoneFieldToNextStoneField();
```

Comment: Using `#id` becomes problematic in the longrun, if you are not close to finishing, abandon it and start using classes.

Comment: Why would it be problematic? I was taught to use id's if the tag exists only once and else classes. Yet in a lot of tutorials they NEVER use id's. Is it better for JavaScript to completely go with classes instead of id's? With only html and css (no js) id's make the code more readable imo. I'm new in JavaScript, and if you say avoid using id's and convetion is solely classes, I will start doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution:

```
function dragFromStoneFieldToNextStoneField() {
    let dragStone = document.querySelector("#stoneField").querySelectorAll(".stone");
    let putCircleNextStoneField = document.querySelector("#nextStoneField");
    let currentStone;

    dragStone.forEach(stone => {
        stone.classList.add("cursorPointer");
    });

    dragStone.forEach(stone => {
        stone.addEventListener("dragstart", () => {
            currentStone = stone;
        });
    });

    putCircleNextStoneField.addEventListener("dragover", e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        putCircleNextStoneField.classList.add("draggedOver");

        putCircleNextStoneField.appendChild(currentStone);

    });

    putCircleNextStoneField.addEventListener("dragleave", e => {
        putCircleNextStoneField.classList.remove("draggedOver");
    });

    putCircleNextStoneField.addEventListener("drop", e => {
        putCircleNextStoneField.classList.remove("draggedOver");
    });
}

dragFromStoneFieldToNextStoneField();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think that referencing the node is better but I'll post here in the case someone in the future need a example of [setData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setData) and [getData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/getData):

```js
function receive(event) {
  const sourceId = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  
  // find the element and clone it
  const element = document.getElementById(sourceId).cloneNode(true);
  const container = document.querySelector(".target");
  container.appendChild(element);
}

function onDrag(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id);
}

function allowDrop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
.target {
  padding: 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px dashed #2a2;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.container {
   margin: 20px 0;
   display: flex;
}

.source {
  background-color: #f8f8ff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 8px;
  color: #08c;
}

.source:hover {
  background-color: #f0f0ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="target" ondrop="receive(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  drop here
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div id="item-104" class="source" draggable="true" ondragstart="onDrag(event)">
    draggable #104
  </div>
  <div id="item-208" class="source" draggable="true" ondragstart="onDrag(event)">
    draggable #208
  </div>
  <div id="item-37" class="source" draggable="true" ondragstart="onDrag(event)">
    draggable #37
  </div>
</div>
```